# can i override a class variable in a sub class and change its type to a sub class

Tags: c#, inheritance

is there a way to override a variable in a subclass, but also change the type to be a subclass of that type.
ie.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass() { }
    protected virtual MyBase WorkField { get { return new MyBase(); } }
    public int WorkProperty
    {
        get { return WorkField.Value; }
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass():base() { }

    /* I get an error here saying that WorkField needs to be MyBase type*/
    protected override MyExtend WorkField 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return new MyExtend(); 
        }
    }

    //public new int WorkProperty
    //{
    //    get { return 0; }
    //}
}

public class MyBase
{
    public int Value = 1;
}

public class MyExtend : MyBase
{
    public int value = 20;
}
```

is there a way to do similar to this, but valid?
so i can have a superClass that does task on MyBase, and then have a subclass that does things on the MyEntend version of it.
without casting it everytime i use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to change the signature in this case.  Just return the derived type:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass():base() { }

    protected override MyBase WorkField 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return new MyExtend(); 
        }
    }

    //public new int WorkProperty
    //{
    //    get { return 0; }
    //}
}
```

The polymorphic behavior of your subclass will allow you to return it.

Answer (score 1):

For overriding the signature should be of the base base method.

```
public class BaseClass<T> where T : MyBase, new()
{
    public BaseClass() { }
    protected virtual T WorkField { get { return new T(); } }
    public int WorkProperty { get { return WorkField.Value; } }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<MyBase>
{
    public DerivedClass() : base() { }
```

// same error occurs as base property is of type "MyBase"

> protected override MyExtend WorkField { get { return new MyExtend();
>   } }

```
    //public new int WorkProperty
    //{
    //    get { return 0; }
    //}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class BaseClass<T> where T: MyBase, new()
    {
        public BaseClass() { }
        protected virtual T WorkField { get { return new T(); } }
        public int WorkProperty { get { return WorkField.Value; } }
    }

    public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<MyExtend>
    {
        public DerivedClass() : base() { }
        protected override MyExtend WorkField { get { return new MyExtend(); } }

        //public new int WorkProperty
        //{
        //    get { return 0; }
        //}
    }

    public class MyBase
    {
        public MyBase()
        {

        }
        public int Value = 1;
    }
    public class MyExtend : MyBase
    {
        public int value = 20;
    }
```